# My hosting is messing up my urls

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, path

Usually when I get the url of a request i use Request.RawUrl.

This gives /default.aspx for example.

However recently my host changed something and now the name of the application directory is displayed as well so i get /appdirname/default.aspx.

Now why does it give me the directory of the application? It looks as if my website is a subapplication of another website. So when you go to mydomain.com the rawurl will be:

/appdirname/default.aspx

I believe each domain has it's own website defined in iis or am i mistaken.

I am not asking for a workaround, which should be pretty straightforward, I am asking why this is happening and how, what kind of IIS setup causes this to happen?

PS.

And the worst part is i had this issue with godaddy and i was happy my host didnt have it but now both hosts have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Request.RawUrl method returns everything after the domain declaration, so if your full url is:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com:8080/directory/Page.aspx
```

then the method will return

```
/directory/Page.aspx
```

That's all it does. That's all it claims to do. As you say, your hosting provider must have changed something, which is very naughty, and the workaround should be easy. There is a good chance that they have introduced some kind of url redirection, but the best way to find out is to get in touch with their helpdesk and ask them what is happening. I find that most successful hosting companies tend to respond in good time to this kind of question. Otherwise they tend to become formerly-successful hosting companies.

Ric Strahl has this to say about it: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx

Comment: I have a vague idea of what might be happening i'll try to write about it later, thanks for the answer.